# sql statement is not working with image upload

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am doing an image upload form and the image uploads just fine but after the image loads the sql statement is not working. I was wondering how I can fix this also this is my first time trying prepared statements so idk if my syntax is right or what.

```
<?php

// Check for errors
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
    die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
}

// Check filetype
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != 'image/png'){
    die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
}

// Check filesize
if($_FILES['file_upload']['size'] > 500000){
    die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
}

//Rename File
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$filename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . "png";

// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], '../images/' . $filename)){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}

// die('File uploaded successfully.');

session_start();

require_once('connection.php');

$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO items (poster, item_name, item_desc, item_type, item_price, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param($poster, $item_name, $item_desc, $item_type, $item_price, $link);

$item_type = $_POST['item_type'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_desc = $_POST['item_desc'];
$item_price = $_POST['item_price'];
$poster = $_SESSION['username'];
$link = $filename;

$poster = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_name = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_desc = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_type = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_price = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$link = filter_var($item_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql->execute();

?>
```

Comment: You should check the manual, the first parameter of `bind_param()` should be the string with the types.

Comment: [The manual should be your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: I forgot that just added that param in and time to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to define the data types in `bind_param`. Something like below:

```
$sql->bind_param('ssssds',$poster, $item_name, $item_desc, $item_type, $item_price, $link);
```

Comment: You might want to do a quick count there buddy

Comment: Aaah! it's kind of hard to see from small screen

Comment: Have the last one on me

Answer (score 0):

Please note always start php session in first line as top of all codes

```
<?php
session_start();
```

and set type of values in first item as

```
$sql->bind_param("ssssss", $poster, $item_name, $item_desc, $item_type, $item_price, $link);
```

and after execute Don't forgot about close statements :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to move this line at the top of your script just to be safe.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Because the variables you are using in the `bind_param` do not yet exist, you have to do the varibale creation before the `bind_param`

If the variables existed it would have been fine to set new vaues into the existing variables in the order you originally had the `bind_param` and data assignment.

You can also reduce the code a bit and filter the post variable rather than go through a new set of scalar variables. You were also filtering `$item_type` into all the variables. haha Copy/Paste will get you every time.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO items (poster, item_name, item_desc, item_type, item_price, link) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");


$poster     = filter_var($_SESSION['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_name  = filter_var($_POST['item_name'],   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_desc  = filter_var($_POST['item_desc'],   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_type  = filter_var($_POST['item_type'],   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_price = filter_var($_POST['item_price'],  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$link       = filter_var($filename,             FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql->bind_param('ssssds',$poster, $item_name, $item_desc, $item_type, $item_price, $link);
```